# How to convert ejs to jade?

Tags: node.js, pug, ejs

I have troubles converting the following ejs to jade:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

How does this block look in jade?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd write this as follows:

```
if message.length
  .alert.alert-danger= message
```

... as `message` is a string, `message.length` evaluates to a falsy value (0) only if it's an empty string. I've also used `buffered output` here (note that `=` character) so that `message` value will be HTML escaped.

An alternative approach is comparing `message` with an empty string directly:

```
if message !== ''
  .alert.alert-danger= message
```

Note that I dropped `div` in `div.alert.alert-danger` expression, as it's kind of default element for Jade templates. Have you used any other element, you'd have to start the expression with its tagname.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade

```
- if(message.length>0){
   div.alert.alert-danger #{message}
- }
```